Drop-outs in RCT
I have conducted a RCT with 34 participants, experimental group and a control group. We took measurement data before randomisation at baseline (T0), and then follow-up measurements every 4 months (so T1 and 4 months, T2 at 8 months, and last one at 12 months was T3). The intervention was conducted in a company, during their working hours.
I have 4 participants that dropped out right after T0, (and thus have no follow-up data at all) and the reasons are quite random:  changed jobs (n=2), retired (n=1), got injured during sports and had a long sick leave (n=1).
I think that since the drop-out reasons are not related at all with our study and have no connection with the outcomes, the best idea is to exclude these 4 participants.
Is that reasonable? Should I be doing something else instead?
Thank you so much in advance!!

It sounds then that you can make the missing at random assumption (MAR).  That does not mean that it's a good idea to drop subjects with incomplete data (which requires a missing completely at random assumption (MCAR) and reduces precesion/power).  Instead use all available data in the analysis, using a full likelihood method that requires MAR, e.g., generalized least squares (aka growth curve models), mixed effects models, Markov models, or Bayesian longitudinal models of a similar variety.
